# Problem based on Group Action

Tags: group-theory

If G be a group of order O,where O is the nth power of a prime p, n is greater than or equal to 1.Let N be a normal subgroup of order p.We have to show that N is a subset of Z(G).
Where should I use group action to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

If $g \in G$ and $x \in N$, let $g.x=gxg^{-1}\in N$ because $N$ is a normal subgroup. $N$ is a cyclic group because $N$ is subgroup of order $p$.
Let $x_0$ a generator of $N$.
Let $S(x_0)=\{g\in G |g.x_0=x_0\}$
Let $O(x_0)=\{g.x_0 |g \in G\}$.

$|O(x_0)|\times |S(x_0)|=p^n$.

So $|O(x_0)|$ divides $p^n$. But $|O(x_0)|<p$ because $e_G \notin O(x_0)$.
So $O(x_0)=\{x_0\}$ and $x_0\in Z(G)$.

So $N \subset Z(G)$.

Comment: will you please explain how O(x0)×S(x0)=p^n..

Comment: You may see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_action#Orbit-stabilizer_theorem_and_Burnside.27s_lemma

Comment: oh! I forgot that,now I got it..

Answer (score 1):

Let $G$ act on $N$ by conjugation $(g,n) \mapsto gng^{-1}$ which is well-defined since $N$ is a normal subgroup. Then the fixed points are precisely the set $N^{G} = \left\lbrace n \in N : ng = gn \, \forall g \in G\right\rbrace$. It follows that $N^G = N \cap Z(G)$. But you know that $|N| \equiv |N^G| (\text{mod} \, p)$ (holds for $p$-groups, i.e. groups of order $p^n$ for some prime $p$ and positive integer $n$) and since $N$ is a subgroup of order $p$ it follow that $|N^G| = p$. Then we get, since $N\cap Z(G) \subseteq N$, that the order of both sets are equal: $|N\cap Z(G)| = |N| = p$ and therefore $N\cap Z(G) = N$, proving the claim.